# Examining Independence of First and Last Dice Roll Results in a Cumulative Sum Scenario

Tags: probability

I'm trying to solve a scenario where a fair die is rolled repeatedly until the cumulative sum of all rolls is at least 4, after which the process is halted.

I've defined two random variables:

1. $X$, which represents the outcome of the first die roll.
2. $Z$, which corresponds to the outcome of the final die roll.

I am trying to determine whether $X$ and $Z$ can be considered as independent random variables.

Here's my attempt so far:

The support of $X$ and $Z$ is both $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. I then constructed a joint distribution table with $X$ values populating the top row and $Z$ values constituting the left-most column:

| - | $X=1$ | $X=2$ | $X=3$ | $X=4$ | $X=5$ | $X=6$ | $P(X=x)$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $Z=1$ | ? | ? | 1/36 | 0 | 0 | 0 | ? |
| $Z=2$ | ? | ? | 1/36 | 0 | 0 | 0 | ? |
| $Z=3$ | ? | ? | 1/36 | 0 | 0 | 0 | ? |
| $Z=4$ | ? | ? | 1/36 | 1/6 | 0 | 0 | ? |
| $Z=5$ | ? | ? | 1/36 | 0 | 1/6 | 0 | ? |
| $Z=6$ | ? | ? | 1/36 | 0 | 0 | 1/6 | ? |
| $P(Z=z)$ | 1/6 | 1/6 | 1/6 | 1/6 | 1/6 | 1/6 | 1 |

In this table, '?' represents the joint probabilities I am trying to calculate, and '0' represents the cases that are impossible (e.g., when $X$  is grater than 3 $Z$ can only be the value of X).

However, I am currently stuck on how to address the cases where $X \leq 2$. I am unsure how to proceed with calculating these joint probabilities or making further simplifications.
I know it's not divided equally between the cells.

Could anyone offer guidance or insights into this problem?

Comment: It should be clear that $X$ can take values $1,2,3,4,5,6$.  It should also be clear that $Z$ can take values $1,2,3,4,5,6$.  It should be clear that $\Pr(X=1\mid Z=1)=\Pr(X=1)=\frac{1}{6}$.  It should be clear that $\Pr(X=6\mid Z=1)=0\neq \Pr(X=6)=\frac{1}{6}$.  Since $\Pr(X=6\mid Z=1)\neq \Pr(X=6)$ the random variables are dependent.

Comment: Note that $\Pr(X=x)=\frac{1}{6}$ for all $x$.  The same is not true for $\Pr(Z=z)$, unlike how your attempted table is structured.  It would appear you have the right idea, but have just swapped the places of these labels.  As for filling out the rest of your joint distribution... (*ignoring that it is hardly necessary for the problem as written*), you could do this by a tedious tree diagram, mapping out all the cases including the potential second and third rolls too.  There are thankfully a relatively small number of cases, but it is still annoying and I wouldn't bother.

Comment: Thank you, how can I calculate the rest of the table? what is the right way to approach it?

Comment: The sequence of rolls (1,1,1,1) occurs with probability $\frac{1}{6^4}$.  Similarly the sequence (1,1,1,2), (1,1,1,3),...,(1,1,1,6).  Then we could also have had the sequences (1,2,1),(1,2,2),(1,2,3),... who each occur with probability $\frac{1}{6^3}$.  Then the sequences (2,1,1),(2,1,2),... who each also occur with probability $\frac{1}{6^3}$.  So, $\Pr(X=1,Z=1)$ for instance happens with probability $\frac{1}{6^4}+\frac{1}{6^3}$ corresponding to the two possibilities (1,1,1,1) and (1,2,1)...

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you very much!

Comment: meanwhile $\Pr(X=1,Z=6)$ happens as (1,1,1,6),(1,2,6),(1,6) with probability $\frac{1}{6^4}+\frac{1}{6^3}+\frac{1}{6^2}$.  Again, tedious...  This is made far far worse if you were to adjust the problem... for instance stopping after the sum reached 50.  It will be "*less dependent*" in that case, but still dependent.  I wouldn't touch that variation of the problem with this approach at all and would instead look for an inductive argument.